# Cannot connect from host to .net core website inside docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have searched about this but cannot find a solution... I have a .NET Core web api project and containerized it inside the docker. My host for docker is a VM in VirtualBox with CentOS 7.5. I run the container using the command:

```
docker run -d -name webapi -p 80:5000 netcorelnx
```

I can then by using the command:

```
docker exec -ti webapi /bin/bash
```

Get to that container and execute inside it:

```
curl localhost:5000/api/values
```

This returns the correct values returned by my .NET Core web api project.
However when I am trying to call this from my host's browser by using the url http://localhost/api/values it says "The connection was reset".
This is my dockerfile:

```
...
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-bionic AS runtime
...
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000
ENTRYPOINT["dotnet", "NetCoreWebApi.dll"]
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual after many hours of investigations and posting a question I have found out a solution. The problem was in the code of the .NET core app which has been not written by me. There was a line:

```
.UseKestrel(options => { options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000); });
```

Instead of

```
.UseKestrel(options => { options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5000); });
```